# Temporarily change Timezone to that of email recipient

Tags: php

Is there a way to set the time zone for one specific email at a time in `PHPMailer`?

People want their notification emails to be in their time zone (so they don't have to do the math), but everywhere else in the app needs to be whatever it's set to already, so global (`date_default_timezone_set(‘Asia/Calcutta’);`) and config file editing is out of the question.

Any hints?

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHPMailer, and everything to do with how you're generating the text of the email...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`date_default_timezone_set()` is **NOT** global. What is set global sits either in `php.ini` or is set via `.htaccess`. Calling `date_default_timezone_set()` sets TZ in scope of invoking script only, so simply calling it prior building mail should be perfectly sufficient

Comment: Right, I feel dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object makes it a breeze :)

```php
$myTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$myTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
```

[**example**](http://3v4l.org/F9O5d)